# How to handle CORS for web workers?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

In one of my js files **(game.js)**, web workers are used which causes problems for CORS.

From **game.js:**

```
var engine = new Worker(options.machinejs|| 'static/js/mainjs/machine.js');
```

First problem I got was about SharedArrayBuffer is not defined and I solved it by adding the needed headers.

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    resp = make_response(render_template("index.html"))
    resp.headers['Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy'] = 'require-corp'
    resp.headers['Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy'] = 'same-origin'
    return resp
```

I got rid of that error but got this one:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/js/mainjs/machine.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE 304
```

When I check the responses I can see the header parts I added for "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" but I see no such headers for
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/js/mainjs/machine.js`
In fact, it warns me to add

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

in my document. Where and how though?

Answer (score 1):

I obviously confused CORS with CORP although they're related.

The solution I found was:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.after_request
def add_header_home(response):
    response.headers['Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy'] = 'require-corp'
    response.headers['Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy'] = 'same-origin'
    return response
```

Somehow after_request decorator helps us here.